# Watch window or evaluate expressions while debugging in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I really like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), it's a great editor but one thing is really annoying me while debugging Node apps:

I can't see any sort of watch window or the ability to evaluate expressions while debugging. This makes debugging pretty painful and I'm considering moving back to VS 2013.

I know we have the local and global variables windows but they are a pain to look through (maybe add a search box?) and some things just don't appear in the list.

For example using TypeScript, a class function compiles down to something like this:

```
Stack.prototype.push = function (item) {
    if (this.items.length == this.length)
        this.resize(length * 2);
    this.items[this.length++] = item;
};
```

When debugging this function however I don't have any access to the `this` variable while in the `push()` function. It does not appear in either the local or global variables and I can't evaluate it anywhere.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Since version 0.6.0 VS Code supports watches and since 0.8.0 VS Code has a debug console (aka REPL).

The "missing this" problem has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Andre! Any ideas when the next release is due?

Comment: Our plan is to release about every 4 weeks.

Comment: @AndreWeinand When will we be able to evaluate expressions without adding watches in order to do so?

Comment: @Spooky this is possible since two releases of vscode

Comment: @AndreWeinand Oh, yeah, I just found it. I tried clicking everything but I missed that one little "Open Console" button. Would you like to update your answer?