# How do I evaluate expressions while debugging in VS Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, evaluate

[image]I am using vscode to build my golang gin project.

I go to debugging mod and can not do evaluate expressions.

I want to go some line and evaluate that see what happened in that monent.

Like eclipse ctrl+shift+i or idea ctrl+alt+f8

Quick evaluate expression.

I also see this

[Eclipse inspection (Ctrl + Shift + I) equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073545/eclipse-inspection-ctrl-shift-i-equivalent-in-intellij-idea-community-edi)

[Watch window or evaluate expressions while debugging in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138096/watch-window-or-evaluate-expressions-while-debugging-in-vs-code)

```golang
func main() {
    
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/user/:name", func(c *gin.Context) {
    name := c.Param("name")
    c.String(http.StatusOK, name, 1, 2, 3, 4)

})
```

when the debugger line in  name := c.Param("name")

I try to use the bottom of vscode window and when I type this code into the command it will return

but if I type name it will return the right string for me.

> Failed to eval expression:
> {
> "Expr": "c.Param("name")",
> "Scope": {
> "goroutineID": 34,
> "frame": 1
> },
> "Cfg": {
> "followPointers": true,
> "maxVariableRecurse": 1,
> "maxStringLen": 64,
> "maxArrayValues": 64,
> "maxStructFields": -1
> }
> }
> Eval error: function calls not allowed without using 'call'

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is a limitation of the language's debugging tools: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2225

It seems like pretty basic debugging functionality to be missing...

Comment: Thanks...that is amazing

Answer (score 63):

For the ones coming here at 2020+, it is now possible to call a function. The syntax is:

```
call functionToBeCalled(arg1, arg2)
```

In the question ask for running an assignation, you can also set a variable

```
call variable = newValue
```

Source: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/100

Comment: I added this to the Debug Console and it worked:
```functioToBeCalled(arg1, arg2)```

Comment: Thanks , I already using jetbrain goland for one year.

Comment: You can also set a property of an object in the debug console: 
`call myObject.myProperty="some new property value"`

Comment: @石荒人 are you able to call a function in jetbrain goland while execution is stopped in a debug break point?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible right now as more complex evaluations have only been added to the Delve debugger recently. You might want to follow these two Github issues:

[Add ability to safely call functions #119](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/119#issuecomment-470589828)

[Function calls via delve 'call' are not supported #2655](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2655)

Answer (score 5):

Type your expression here or select code in source file, right click and select Evaluate in Debug Console.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but I got the error: "Unable to evaluate expression: function calls not allowed without using 'call'". Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: "Evaluate in Debug Console" is just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @AlvaroLeandroCavalcante you just have to prefix the expression with call
for eg: `call listTileLst.length`

Answer (score 2):

If you run into an error like `"call not at safe point"`, make sure you've stopped at a breakpoint which is not on a line **declaring** a function, but **inside the body** of a function.

Apparently function declaration lines are not a safe point for the debugger